# Android project building failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've updated Android Studio to 2022.2.1 and I'm getting this build error:

> Cause: class clojure.lang.Reflector cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacRoundEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @e1b0346

At the same time, when I create a new simple project I don't get this error and the project is built successfully.

P.S. I haven't updated the gradle plugin yet.

I've tried building with the updated gradle plugin (8 version) and not upgrading.

Comment: It's possible that the error you are encountering is caused by a conflict between your existing project's configuration and the updated Android Studio version